# IE8 SCRIPT438: object doesn't support property or method 'addeventlistener'

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I run my web application (html+javascript, jquery, Bootstrap) application in IE 8 browser using F12.

I am getting this error.

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

I am using this lib's libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: we actually need to see some code.

Comment: i am getting this error in jquery.min.js file
............................................................................................


a.removeEventListener("load",S),r.ready()}"complete"===d.readyState||"loading"!==d.readyState&&!d.documentElement.doScroll?a.setTimeout(r.ready):(d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",S),a.addEventListener("load",S));var T=function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g){var h=0,i=a.length,j=null==c;if("object"==

Answer (score 0):

jQuery version 3.2.1 does not support Internet Explorer 8.

Quoted from [jQuery's browser support page](https://jquery.com/browser-support/):

> If you need to support older browsers like Internet Explorer 6-8, Opera 12.1x or Safari 5.1+, use [jQuery 1.12](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/#jquery-all-1.x).

Comment: still not working patrick hund